# What kind of data should/can each SQS message contain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

Suppose I have a task of updating an user via a third party API call. Is it okay to put the actual user data inside the message (if it fits)? Or should I only provide an ID in the message so the worker can retrieve the updated record from my local database?

Comment: Are you asking if it is *legally* OK to store the information in the SQS message?

Comment: @MarkB: I wonder if it's best practice to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what level of compliance is required for your infrastructure, to see what kind of data you want to put in the queue.

If there aren't any compliance restrictions, you are free to put any kind of data in your own infrastructure on AWS.